# SharePoint migration from 2010 to 2010 Lift and shift

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, migration

We are planning a SharePoint migration from one location to another location. There is no version upgrade. It is from SP 2010 to SP 2010. From most the online content speaks about the migrating from one version to another.

Looking for a good step by step approach documented\best practises, considerations for 2010 to 2010 migration.

Comment: More information required, from one location to 2nd location means moving the server to new domains, or just moving the the data to new farm? will all user be in new location?

Comment: Just moving from one farm to other farm. Same domain

Answer (score 2):

1. Create the new Farm (or Single Server or whatever configuration you want) and configure it (services, etc.) but don't deploy a site.
2. Backup only Content Database for the existing site and restore it to whatever name you like on the new farm.
3. Create a new application on the new farm being sure to set the Content DB name so you can easily find it; do not deploy a site.
4. Using the STSADM (stsadm -o addcontentdb) or PowerShell command, attach the restored database to the new site (you must do this from the command line).
5. During the attach, if there are any problems, SharePoint will notify you - this includes missing web parts, etc. (see note below).
6. When complete, open Central Administration and go to the content DB's under Application Management. Make sure you have the correct application selected (the one you just created/attached the content DB to). You should see both DB's listed along with the number of sites - so first one should have 0 then restored one should have > 0 (if you have zero, it didn't work).
7. Assuming all is well, select and delete the original application DB (from step 3) or delete it using STSADM (stsadm -o deletecontentdb) or PowerShell.
8. Run an IISReset for good measure and the site should pop up just fine. BE AWARE: Any hard coded links to the old URL will fail (this is a known issue with moving sites).

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, same SharePoint version, same domain and just new farm.i would do this way

- configure the new farm same version( you already did)
- configure the web application with same authentication as source farm
- Configure Services Application Same As Source farm
- Deploy and configure any customization, 3rd party webparts, custom web.config changes and other changes
- Now Backup the content database from source farm and restore it into new farm Sql server. Apply service account permission.
- Now Mount the content database to web applications.
- Test It
- switch your dns...point to the new web front ends.

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure the new farm in the same way as the old one (you already did)
2. Adjust the web application's authentication to match the source farm's
3. Configure the Services Application in the same way as the source farm is configured.
4. Any customizations, 3rd party webparts, custom web.config changes, and other changes should be deployed and configured.
5. Now back up the source farm's content database and restore it to the new farm's SQL server. Allow access to the service account.
6. Now you can use web applications to access the content database.
7. Put it to the test.
8. Change your DNS settings to point to the new web front ends.